# Batch compiling java from multiple directories

Tags: java, deployment, javac

In an eclipse project, java code is spread out in directories matching the package names.  Internally, they are compiling all the java code.

Suppose there are two files which reference each other, A.java and B.java.  Each is in a separate package a and b as follows:

```
a/
  a.java

b/
  b.java
```

For any single directory, the java compiler can build everything:

javac -d ../bin *.java

but given that there are a number of directories, and code must be compiled at the same time, how does the compiler get told?  Is there a recursive "compile it all" kind of command like:

javac -d ../bin -r src

The reason for this question is that we have a project to deploy on a server.  So if someone wants to say the correct way to deploy is to build war files and move them to the server, that's good too, but I still would like to know, for a generic tree of code, if there is an easy way to compile it all.

Comment: Have you considered using build tools such as Ant or Maven to manage the compilation process? With respect to "how does the compiler get told?", you'll need to add the path to the other directory in the _classpath_.

Comment: ant is just managing how the compile happens.  I want to know the commands it outputs, the equivalent of make -n.  After all, in order for ant to successfully compile a program containing 30 directories in which code from each directory refers to others, it will have to compile each code simultaneously (ie in the same compile).

Comment: You can use _ant -verbose_ or _ant -debug_ to see the output.